# How to load API data from a viewmodel before mainactivity loads

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit, viewmodel

I am trying to retrieve data from the Open Weather API through my ViewModel before my main activity loads up. the problem is that I think im pulling from the ViewModel before I retrieve the data which is causing a crash.

is there a way to populate the UI only when the API is finished loading? or should i try to use Dummy data and update the data once the API call is finished

My main activity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        val viewModel: WeatherViewModel by viewModels()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            WeatherTheme {
                val text by viewModel.searchText.collectAsState()
                var active by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                val weather = viewModel.openWeather.observeAsState()
                val mutableList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
                var prevItems = remember {
                    mutableList
                }

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    SearchBar(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        query = text,
                        onQueryChange = viewModel::onSearchTextChanged,
                        onSearch = {
                            if(prevItems.size > 14)
                                prevItems.clear()
                            prevItems.add(text)
                            active = false
                        },
                        active = active,
                        onActiveChange = {
                            active = it
                        },
                        placeholder = {
                            Text(text = "Search")
                        },
                        leadingIcon = {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Default.Search,
                                contentDescription = "Search Icon"
                            )
                        },
                        trailingIcon = {
                            if (active) {
                                Icon(
                                    modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                                        if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                                            viewModel.emptyText()
                                        } else {
                                            active = false
                                        }
                                    },
                                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Close,
                                    contentDescription = "Close Icon"
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    ) {
                        prevItems.forEach {
                            Row(modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(all = 14.dp)
                                .clickable { viewModel.onSearchTextChanged(it) }
                                .fillMaxWidth()) {
                                Icon(
                                    modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 10.dp),
                                    imageVector = Icons.Default.History,
                                    contentDescription = "Search History Icon"
                                )
                                Text(it)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Text(text = viewModel.emptyText().toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

    }
}
```

my view model

```
package com.example.weather.viewmodel

import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.weather.api.RetrofitInstance
import com.example.weather.api.WeatherApi
import com.example.weather.model.OpenWeather
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class WeatherViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _searchText = MutableStateFlow("")
    val searchText = _searchText.asStateFlow()

    private val _isSearching = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isSearching = _isSearching.asStateFlow()

    //note: you are unable to use stateflows in Java projects.

    private val _openWeather = MutableLiveData<OpenWeather>()
    val openWeather: LiveData<OpenWeather> = _openWeather

    private val _name = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val name: LiveData<String> = _name

    init {
        getWeatherData()
    }


    private fun getWeatherData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            Log.v("WeatherViewModel", "Loading...")
            try {
                _openWeather.value = RetrofitInstance.api.getWeatherUSCity()
                _name.value = _openWeather.value!!.name
                Log.v("Name: ", "${name.value}")
                Log.v("WeatherViewModel", "Success!")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("WeatherViewModel", "Failure: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }

    fun onSearchTextChanged(text: String) {
        _searchText.value = text
    }

    fun emptyText() {
        _searchText.value = ""
    }
}
```

my data class

```
data class OpenWeather(
    val coord: Coord = Coord(0.0,0.0),
    val id: Int = 0,
    val main: Main = Main(0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0),
    val name: String = "name",
    val sys: Sys = Sys("US",0, 0.0,0,0,0),
    val weather: List<Weather> = listOf<Weather>(),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can'not load data before activity loads up. But you can make loading animation which show only when data is loading and then display actual data when API call will be finished.

Also I noticed that you are using LiveData but in your project you have kotlin Flow so I replaced LiveData with Flow.

Here is an example:

```
class WeatherViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(WeatherUiState.Loading)
    val uiState: StateFlow<WeatherUiState>
        get() = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        getWeatherData()
    }

    private fun getWeatherData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val weather = WeatherUiState.Success(RetrofitInstance.api.getWeatherUSCity())
                _uiState.value = WeatherUiState.Success(
                    weather = weather,
                    name = weather.name
                )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _uiState.value = WeatherUiState.Error
            }
        }
    }
}

sealed interface WeatherUiState {
    data class Success(
        val weather: OpenWeather,
        val name: String
    ) : WeatherUiState
    object Error : WeatherUiState
    object Loading : WeatherUiState
}
```

**Explanation:** uiState has initial state 'loading'. With this managment of states you can display data on screen based on state's value.

**Example of displaying data:**

```
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    val viewModel: WeatherViewModel by viewmodels()
    
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    
    when (uiState) {
        is WeatherUiState.Success -> // display weather data
        WeatherUiState.Error -> // display error message on screen
        WeatherUiState.Loading -> // show loading animation
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your sealed classes implements WeatherUiState?